# Redirecting with HTACCESS from iindex.php?r=sdft2345 to just dft2345 , possible?

Tags: .htaccess, web

Lets say i have the next link:

```
mydomain.com/index.php?r=sdft2345
```

and i want it to be:

```
mydomain.com/sdft2345
```

is it possible? if not so how short can i make it? 
I failed to understand the writing of HTACCESS and if someone can be a bit more clear about it, il be glad.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Yess, that is possible. Add this in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/?$ index.php?r=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just modifying what Marshall wrote:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?r=$1 [NC,L]
```

That will cover everything.

Breaking that down, here's what each part does:

`RewriteRule` - just telling the server what will follow.

`^(.*)$` - Any regular expression.  This is used to capture and breakdown the URL.

`index.php?r=$1` - This is what we want the server to actually see.  We're taking the first group that we capture from the prior regular expression and giving it to the server with `$1`.

`[NC,L]` - Various [RewriteRule flags](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html).  `NC` being "nocase" and `L` being "last".